# Playwright: do not reuse existing web server in container environment

Tags: docker, playwright, e2e

I am using playwright for e2e testing of my (angular) web application and loving it so far. I would like to configure playwright test to reuse an existing web server when not in CI environment nor when running from a Docker container.

The [playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-advanced#launching-a-development-web-server-during-the-tests) provide the following example, which was helpful to start the server in CI environment only:

```
  webServer: {
    command: 'npm run start',
    port: 3000,
    timeout: 120 * 1000,
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
  },
```

I was wondering if it would be equally simple to achieve the same behavior when running from a Docker container? Or if instead I should think of another way of doing so (e.g. setting environment variables)?